# CRM Assigning OwnerId to an Activity Using C#

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011

In CRM 2011 I have an Activity entity labelled "activityEntity" in my code. I also have a radio button field named "AssignToCaseOwner" on the Case entity. The Case entity is labelled "sourceCase".

Basically when AssignToCaseOwner is set to Yes, then the Activity will be assigned to the Owner of the Case.

This is the code that I have, but for some reason the Activity keeps getting assigned to the Case creator. Any suggestion is very much appreciated.

Thanks,
-elisabeth

```
//retrieving case Owner
        var sourceCaseColumnSet = new ColumnSet(new[] {"ownerid"});
        var sourceCaseAttributes = sourceCase.RetrieveEntity<Entity>(service, sourceCaseColumnSet);

if ((int)assignToCaseOwner == 1)
        {

            activityEntity.Attributes["ownerid"] = new EntityReference(SystemUser.EntityLogicalName, (Guid)sourceCaseAttributes.Attributes["ownerid"]);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change the `ownerid` property of a record with a normal update, you need to use the `AssignRequest` message.

Account record example:

```
Guid accountId = new Guid("90F8889F-EB95-E781-8417-000C44420CBC");
Guid newOwnerId = new Guid("A8AA28B4-9015-DF11-8062-000E0CA08051");

AssignRequest assignRequest = new AssignRequest
        {
            Assignee = new EntityReference("systemuser", newOwnerId),
            Target = new EntityReference("account", accountId)
        };
service.Execute(assignRequest);
```

Comment: Thanks Guido. I tried below code but still not working, any suggestion?

Comment: did you set the right logicalname inside the Target parameter (instead of "account" string)?

Comment: Yes this is my code:
AssignRequest assignCase = new AssignRequest
               
 {
                    
Assignee = new EntityReference(Schema.SystemUser.EntityLogicalName, (Guid)sourceCaseAttributes.Attributes["ownerid"]),
                    
Target = new EntityReference(Schema.Activity.EntityLogicalName, new Guid(sourceCase.Id.ToString()))
                };

                
service.Execute(assignCase);

Comment: you need to use the logicalname of the exact activity you are using, Schema.Activity looks like to me the generic one, and you are assignign the sourceCase.Id, Id and LogicalName must be from the same entity.

Comment: Ah I got what you mean now. I fixed the Target assignment like below, however it's still not working.

Target = new EntityReference(Schema.Task.EntityLogicalName, new Guid(activityEntity.Id.ToString()))

So you mention that I cannot assign using a generic "activity" entity and must specify for each types of activity (phone, task, etc)?

Comment: yes, you can't use the generic activity. If the record is a Task, the logicalname is "task", if the record is an Appointment will be "appointment" if is a custom activity will be something like "new_activity". You need to check the name under Customizations.

Comment: Still not working even after changing it to "Task". I'll keep looking around... Thanks much for all your help GUido.

Comment: which is the schema name of this entity? can you post a screenshot of the CRM customization form?

Comment: Sorry didn't see this until today GUido. It's actually just the regular CRM Activity entities such as Appointment, Phone, Task, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help. Sorry for the delay in responding.

My code is working now as below. Two-option fields are simply boolean values.

```
var assignToCaseOwner = new_entity.Attributes["new_assigntocaseowner"];

   if ((bool)assignToCaseOwner)
       {             
            activityEntity.Attributes.Add("ownerid", sourceCaseAttributes.Attributes["ownerid"]);

        }
```

Thanks.